# Rails 5.1 Encrypted Secrets RAILS_MASTER_KEY env variable not being read

Tags: environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, secret-key

- I run `export RAILS_MASTER_KEY=************************`.
- I remove the key file from the directory.
- I check that ENV contains RAILS_MASTER_KEY with the correct key, and it does.
- I run `rails console`.
- I've even tried running `RAILS_MASTER_KEY=************************ rails console` to try to force the env var but not no avail

I still get the missing key error

```
Missing encryption key to decrypt secrets with. Ask your team for your master
key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] (Rails::Secrets::MissingKeyError)`
```

Why isn't rails reading the environment variable?
Here's the backtrace if it helps.

```
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:37:in 'key'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:96:in 'encryptor'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:45:in 'decrypt'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:89:in 'preprocess'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in 'block in parse'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:23:in 'each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:23:in 'each_with_object'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/secrets.rb:23:in 'parse'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in 'secrets'
from /Users/user/Company/service/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in 'load'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in 'block in load'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in 'load_dependency'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in 'load'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in 'block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in 'instrument'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in 'load_config_initializer'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in 'block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in 'each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in 'block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'instance_exec'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'run'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in 'block in run_initializers'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in 'block in tsort_each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in 'block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in 'block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in 'each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in 'block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in 'each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in 'tsort_each_child'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in 'call'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in 'each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in 'block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'call'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in 'tsort_each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in 'tsort_each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in 'run_initializers'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in 'initialize!'
from /Users/user/Company/service/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in 'require'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in 'preload'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in 'serve'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in 'block in run'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in 'loop'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in 'run'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from -e:1:in '<main>'
```

### Update

Running `ENV` in my terminal shows the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` but I put a puts `ENV` in my `environments/development.rb` file and the variable is absent.
What?

Answer (score 2):

All my environment variable related problem with Rails were always because of spring. Try `bin/spring stop` then restart your console.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Knshiro that was exactly my problem in a Rails-5.2 app I was working on. Thank you for posting!